# nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am trying same implementation in my `Maven Spring Boot` + `Kafka` application for `Producer` after sending data it is  hitting `Azure Matrix` but mentioned error I am getting error:

```
2019-07-04 12:27:31.729  INFO 92607 --- [nio-8050-exec-2] c.g.k.service.KafkaPublisherService      : sending message='t'
2019-07-04 12:28:31.730 ERROR 92607 --- [nio-8050-exec-2] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='Hi' to topic testhub:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

And for consumer while clean build I am getting below mentioned error:

```
2019-07-04 12:48:26.837  WARN 94752 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
    Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: myeventhubname.servicebus.windows.net:9093
    client-id: kafkaconsumer
    properties:
      sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="myeventhubname Key"
      sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    consumer:
      group-id: testhubconsumer
      properties:
        spring.json:
          use.type.headers: false
          #value.default.type: com.protonforest.kafkademo.consumer.ConsumerMessage
    topics:
      subscriber: testhub

kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: myeventhubname.servicebus.windows.net:9093
    #client-id: kafkapublisher
    properties:
      sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="myeventhubname key"
      sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    template: 
      default-topic: testhub
    producer:
      value-serializer: com.protonforest.kafkademo.publishers.ProducerMessageSerializer

Comment: Can you share your configuration parameters and the code you have written for both producer and conusmer?

Comment: kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: myeventhubname.servicebus.windows.net:9093
    client-id: kafkaconsumer
    properties:
      sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="myeventhubname Primary key"
      sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    consumer:
      group-id: testhubconsumer
      properties:
        spring.json:
          use.type.headers: false
    topics:
      subscriber: testhub

Comment: please format your post. The error means you are unable to connect to the kafka broker